# how to insert special characters in to oracle database

Tags: mysql, oracle

Im trying to run a simple insert statement .But it has some special characters which is giving me error.How to escape it so that it gets inserted in to table as it is .

```
update history set comments = 'my testing's' where id= '1323';
```

Comment: `[oracle]` or `[mysql]`? These are two different database products with different syntaxes in certain cases. Please don't add random tags to your question in the hope of attracting more eyeballs..

Answer (score 3):

Two apostrophes:

```
update history set comments = 'my testing''s' where id= '1323';
                                         ^^
                                         here
```

Comment: what in case if I have character like @ will adding ' works?

Comment: For `@` you don't have to do anything, it is not "special" in this context.

Comment: ok.TQ.one help how to use regex replace function if i have comments in string?

Comment: You're welcome. As of your new question (regular expressions), you should open a brand new topic on Stack Overflow, it is not related to this problem. Provide some examples which describe what you mean. Also, I suggest you accept one of provided answers (to mark this discussion as "solved").

Answer (score 3):

> `update history set comments = 'my testing's' where id= '1323';`

This throws ORA-00933 because apostrophe `'` is same character as single-quote, which we use to bound string literals. So the compiler thought your string finished after `g`, and the the error you got was because it didn't understand what the following `s` meant.

To solve this problem we can escape the apostrophe like this:

```
update history set comments = 'my testing''s' where id= '1323';
```

Explicitly editing a long string can be a pain in the neck, so there is a special syntax `q'[...]'` to escape all the quotes in a string:

```
update history set comments = q'[all testing's done by Baba O'Reilly]' 
where id= '1323';
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ec22/1).

> what in case if I have character like @ will adding ' works?

In this context `@` is not a special character.  There is no need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you may also use q-quoting:

```
update history set comments = q'(my testing's' where id= '1323)';
```

More info [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref344).

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the picture, another useful option are the `CHR(ascii_code)` and `UNISTR(utf_code)` functions.

E.g.:

```
update history set comments = 'my testing' || chr(39) || 's' where id= '1323';
```

To add special chars like Euro:

```
update history set comments = 'His salary is ' || unistr('\20ac') || '786,000' where id= '1323';
```